# Isolated Storage adding caracters at the end of a Stream

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having problems converting long into string.
What I'm doing is trying to save a DateTime.Now.Ticks property in isolatedStorage, then retrieve it afterwords. This is what I did to save it:

```
IsolatedStorageFile appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (var file = appStorage.CreateFile("appState"))
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(file))
    {                    
        sw.Write(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    }
}
```

When I retrieve the file, I do it like this:

```
if (appStorage.FileExists("appState"))
{
    using (var file = appStorage.OpenFile("appState", FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string s = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
        }
    }
    appStorage.DeleteFile("appState");
}
```

Until here I have no problem, but when I try to convert the string I retrieved, the compiler throws a FormatExeption. This are the two ways I tried to do it with:

```
long time = long.Parse(s);
long time = (long)Convert.ToDouble(s);
```

So is there any other ways to so this?

EDIT:
The problem is not in the conversion but rather in the StreamWriter adding extra characters.

Comment: And what is the string you're receiving?

Comment: What does the string being retrieved look like?  Put a breakpoint on your streamreader and step through so you can see the string s value.  There may be something there that cannot be converted.

Comment: One comment... you should use Convert.ToInt64(s) a 64-bit integer is equal to a long here.. don't make it a double first and then cast it.

Comment: `long.Parse(s)` should work, check what `s` is like others have mentioned.

Comment: Your title says "converting string to long", but your first sentence says that you're having trouble "converting long into string." Which is it?

Comment: Well, it seems when I put a breakpoint that the string s has the value of Ticks plus some weird value.
I tried to convert the Ticks into string before saving it and it wroks just fine.

Comment: @User-_- I suggest you change the title and description of this question to indicate that your issue has to do with IsolatedStorageFile putting extra characters at the end of a stream, rather than converting longs to strings or vice versa.  For what it's worth, I just tried your code on my machine and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are seeing some other data at the end. Something else may have written other data to the stream.

I think you should use `StreamWriter.WriteLine()` instead of `StreamWriter.Write()` to write the data and then call `StreamReader.ReadLine()` instead of `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` to read it back in.

Comment: Yes but when I generate the file for the StreamWriter I use CreateFile rather then OpenFile, so the file is overwritten, So I don't think that the Ticks are being rewriten in the same file.

Comment: `Write` does not add newline characters. `WriteLine` does.

Comment: @User-_- Hmm, that's strange then. So if you try my suggestion, it still has the extra characters?